# Explode text into array as per paragraph

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the following text:

```
$test = 'Test This is first line

Test:123

This is Test';
```

I want to explode this string to an array of paragraphs. I wrote the following code but it is not working:

```
$array = explode('\n\n', $test);
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `\r\n` or maybe `PHP_EOL` constant?

Comment: does it work with $test = 'Test This is first line\n\nTest:123\n\nThis is Test'; ? I'm not sure about this, but maybe you need to explicetly include the linebreaks when defining your string as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
$array = explode('\n\n', $test);
```

should have `\n\n` enclosed in double quotes:

```
$array = explode("\n\n", $test);
```

Using single quotes, it looks through the variable `$test` for a literal `\n\n`.  With double quotes, it looks for the evaluated values of `\n\n` which are two carriage returns.

Also, note that the end of line depends on the host operating system.  Windows uses `\r\n` instead of `\n`.  You can get the end of line for the operating system by using the predefined constant `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 7):

You might be on Windows which uses `\r\n` instead of `\n`. You could use a regex to make it universal with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg-split):

```
$array = preg_split('#(\r\n?|\n)+#', $test);
```

**Pattern explanation:**

- `(` : start matching group 1
- `\r\n?|\n` : match `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`
- `)` : end matching group 1
- `+` : repeat one or more times

If you want to split by 2 newlines, then replace `+` by `{2,}`.

---

**Update:** you might use:

```
$array = preg_split('#\R+#', $test);
```

[This extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691) covers the meaning of `\R`. Note that this is only supported in PCRE/perl. So in a sense, it's less cross-flavour compatible.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/.+/',$test, $test)` still is a lot easier IMHO, and does what the OP wants

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Well now that you say it ... I was focused on the "split" idea :p The split solution has got more control if we want to split by 2 newlines or plus :)

Comment: Fair point. Since the OP specified paragraphs as delimiters, I'd have to say your approach is the one to go for

Answer (score 2):

Try double quotes

```
$array = explode("\n\n", $test);
```

Answer (score 1):

did you have try this ?

```
$array = explode("\n", $test);
```

Comment: This splits on newlines, and not paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this text into an array like you describe would be:

```
preg_match_all('/.+/',$string, $array);
```

Since `/./` matches any char, except for line terminators, and the `+` is greedy, it'll match as many chars as possible, until a new-line is encountered.
Using `preg_match_all` ensures this is repeated for each line, too. When I tried this, the output looked like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '$test = \'Test This is first line',
    1 => 'Test:123',
    2 => 'This is Test\';',
  ),
)
```

Also note that line-feeds are different, depending on the environment (`\n` for *NIX systems, compared to `\r\n` for windows, or in some cases a simple `\r`). Perhaps you might want to try `explode(PHP_EOL, $text);`, too

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes in your code, such that the `\n\n` is actually evaluated as two lines. Look below:

`'Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph 2'` =

*Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph 2*

Whereas:

`"Paragraph 1\n\nParagraph 2"` =

*Paragraph 1*

*Paragraph 2*

Also, Windows systems use `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\n\n`. You can detect which line endings the system is using with:

```
PHP_EOL
```

So, your final code would be:

```
$paragraphs = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```