# PHP Regex: How to match \r and \n without using [\r\n]?

Tags: php, regex, newline, pcre

I have tested `\v` (vertical white space) for matching `\r\n` and their combinations, but I found out that `\v` does not match `\r` and `\n`. Below is my code that I am using..

```
$string = "
Test
";

if (preg_match("#\v+#", $string )) {
  echo "Matched";
} else {
  echo "Not Matched";
}
```

To be more clear, my question is, is there any other alternative to match `\r\n`?

Comment: You can use `\s+` I guess. Any reason why you don't want to use `\r\n`?

Comment: @Jerry: \s matches any white space

Comment: Yes, I know, but you asked for an alternative to match `\r\n`, which `\s` does match.

Comment: @Jerry: ok but its not macthes \r\n only, I guessed that \v do the trick but it doesn't

Comment: If you want to match `\r\n` only, simply use `\r\n`... You could combine them together like `[\v\r\n]+`

Comment: @Jerry See my below answer, instead of `\s` you can use `\R` as used in PCRE.

Comment: @hwnd: yes your answer is accepted and I hope everyone to know that

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### PCRE and newlines

[PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) has a superfluity of newline related escape sequences and alternatives.

Well, a nifty escape sequence that you can use here is `\R`. By default `\R` will match Unicode newlines sequences, but it can be configured using different alternatives.

To match any Unicode newline sequence that is in the `ASCII` range.

```
preg_match('~\R~', $string);
```

This is equivalent to the following group:

```
(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85)
```

---

To match any Unicode newline sequence; including newline characters outside the `ASCII` range and both the line separator (`U+2028`) and paragraph separator (`U+2029`), you want to turn on the `u` (*unicode*) flag.

```
preg_match('~\R~u', $string);
```

The `u` (*unicode*) modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE and Pattern strings are treated as (**UTF-8**).

The is equivalent to the following group:

```
(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85|\x{2028}|\x{2029})
```

---

It is possible to restrict `\R` to match `CR`, `LF`, or `CRLF` only:

```
preg_match('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R~', $string);
```

The is equivalent to the following group:

```
(?>\r\n|\n|\r)
```

### Additional

Five different conventions for indicating line breaks in strings are supported:

```
(*CR)        carriage return
(*LF)        linefeed
(*CRLF)      carriage return, followed by linefeed
(*ANYCRLF)   any of the three above
(*ANY)       all Unicode newline sequences
```

---

**Note**: `\R` does not have special meaning inside of a character class. Like other unrecognized escape sequences, it is treated as the literal character "R" by default.

Comment: wow! I never used it, that's what I looked for :) see this example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/phd-ebj

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Comment: +1 for `\R`. For academic purposes only, if you're not in `u` mode, you can invent this other way of matching `\r` or `\n` without using them: `(?![ \t\cK\f])\s` Why? because `\s` matches `[ \t\cK\f\r\n]`, so this is a form of class subtraction. :)

Comment: Be careful. I had problems using the capture group '~\R~' with russian words. When this regex is applied to the word "необходимости" it becomes "необ� одимости".

Comment: @PedroSousa why did you omit the `u` pattern modifier?  You need to tell the regex engine when you want to read multibyte characters in the input string.

Comment: This might be obvious to others, but I thought the tildes in `~\R~` were part of the escape sequence. The tildes are just delimiters, which are normally `/`. So it's just the `\R` that's the interesting part.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't answer the question for alternatives, because [`\v`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Whitespace) works perfectly well

> `\v` matches any character considered vertical whitespace; *this includes the platform's carriage return and line feed characters* (newline) plus several other characters, all listed in the table below.

You only need to change `"#\v+#"` to either

- `"#\\v+#"` escape the backslash

or

- `'#\v+#'` use single quotes

In both cases, you will get a match for any combination of `\r` and `\n`.

*Update:*

Just to make the scope of `\v` clear in comparison to `\R`, from [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5cR)

> - **\R**
>     `\R` matches a generic newline; that is, anything considered a linebreak sequence by Unicode. *This includes all characters matched by `\v`* (vertical whitespace), ...

Answer (score 6):

If there is some strange requirement that prevents you from using a literal `[\r\n]` in your pattern, you can always use hexadecimal escape sequences instead:

```
preg_match('#[\xD\xA]+#', $string)
```

This is pattern is equivalent to `[\r\n]+`.

Answer (score 1):

To match every LINE of a given String, simple use the `^$` Anchors and advice your regex engine to operate in multi-line mode. Then `^$` will match the start and end of each line, instead of the whole strings start and end.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

in PHP, that would be the `m` modifier after the pattern. `/^(.*?)$/m` will simple match each line, seperated by any vertical space inside the given string.

Btw: For line-Splitting, you could also use `split()` and the `PHP_EOL` constant:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need the multiline option, or dotall option if using dot. It goes at the end of the delimiter.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php

```
$string = "
Test
";
if(preg_match("#\v+#m", $string ))
echo "Matched";
else
echo "Not Matched";
```

Comment: this is not makes \v to match \r\n

Comment: Multiline mode is irrelevant.  Many regex users jump to the conclusion that you have to specify multiline mode whenever the target string contains line separators.  All it does is tweak the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`), so they'll match at line boundaries (i.e. before and after line separators).  The OP's regex doesn't contain any anchors.

Answer (score 0):

To match a newline in PHP, use the php constant `PHP_EOL`. This is crossplatform.

```
if (preg_match('/\v+' . PHP_EOL ."/", $text, $matches ))
   print_R($matches );
```

Comment: watch out for greedy matches! you might get too much.

Answer (score 0):

This regex also matches newline `\n` and carriage return `\r`  characters.

```
(?![ \t\f])\s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zM6jE1/1)

To match one or more newline or carriage return characters, you could use the below regex.

```
(?:(?![ \t\f])\s)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zM6jE1/2)