# Replacing regular line breaks and unicode line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I have text with paragraph formats, a **date** is always above each paragraph article. The problem is after each article, there is unknown line breaks that are different kind of unicode line breaks. I need to remove every instance of the line breaks between each paragraph and replace it with two `\n\n`.

So from this

```
05/12
The 1959 Mexico hurricane was a devastating tropical cyclone
that was one of the worst ever Pacific hurricanes. It 
impacted the Pacific coast of Mexico in October 1959. The
hurricane killed at least 1,000 people.




11/01
The 1959 Mexico hurricane was a devastating tropical cyclone
that was one of the worst ever Pacific hurricanes. It 
impacted the Pacific coast of Mexico in October 1959. The
hurricane killed at least 1,000 people.
```

To this

```
05/12
The 1959 Mexico hurricane was a devastating tropical cyclone
that was one of the worst ever Pacific hurricanes. It 
impacted the Pacific coast of Mexico in October 1959. The
hurricane killed at least 1,000 people.

11/01
The 1959 Mexico hurricane was a devastating tropical cyclone
that was one of the worst ever Pacific hurricanes. It 
impacted the Pacific coast of Mexico in October 1959. The
hurricane killed at least 1,000 people.
```

I tried using `preg_replace()` but it's not matching every instance?

```
$text = preg_replace('/\r?\n+(?=\d{2}\/\d{2})/', "\n\n", $text);
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to try to match all unicode characters that represent 'line breaks'? I know of another that was screwing up a text tokenizer of mine a week ago - carriage return `\r`. That's just a hint though... **Scratch that** looks like you are matching `\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted on a similar [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691) about this a month or so back.

To match anything considered a linebreak sequence, you can use `\R`

> \R matches a generic newline; that is, anything considered a linebreak sequence by Unicode. This includes all characters matched by \v (vertical whitespace) and the multi character sequence \x0D\x0A.

Try this instead.

```
$text = preg_replace('~\R+(?=\d{2}/\d{2})~u', "\n\n", $text);
```

See the [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) documentation on different ways to implement this.

Comment: In case `\R` is not supported `(\n|\r|\n\r)` may be used