# How to parse \n symbols in text from text area with PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, textarea, newline

I have a text area, I need parse text when form is submitted.

For example I need to get first string from this text area, get it and left whole text as is. I don't want to use `nl2br` function and then use pattern with `<br />`. Can I just parse `\n` chars and if so how? I can't do it in my php code, but I can in regex tester link to example is below.

http://regex101.com/r/mK7hF2

this is my code that doesn't work:

```
preg_match('/(.+)\n\n/', $_POST['text'],$title);

$title = $title[0];

echo $title;
```

it returns nothing. Help me to change this, thanks.

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Use double-quotes. [RTFM](http://php.net/string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for this, use [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
$title = strtok( $_POST['text'], "\n" );
```

**Edit**

Ok, try then with `\R` to match any type of line endings `'/(.+)\R/'`

Comment: at least it work =), but I'm looking for regex solution. If I didn't found another solution for exactly my question I will mark this as right answer.

Comment: that's made it! as @hwnd said `this matches Unicode newlines sequences` this must be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in `php`:

```
$re = '/(.+)\n\n/'; 
$str = "first string\n\nsecond string\n\nother strings bla bla bla"; 
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches))
   echo $matches[1];
else
   echo "nope";
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
first string
```

It is important to use double quotes in input `$str` so that `\n` is interpreted as newline character.

**[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/wYC4LW)**

Comment: this definitely work with this example, but doesn't with `$_POST['text']` (this is text area). Why?

Comment: Can you show output of `var_dump($_POST['text']);` ?

Comment: string(46) "first string second string other strings"

Comment: That means where is no `\n` in your input string. Try this regex: **`$re = '/(\S+)/';`**

Comment: this pattern is work. But I don't understand why there is no `\n`? I'll add the text area screenshot to my question for you to see that there must be `\n`. By the way, if I use `nl2br` text formatting looks like in text area so, there must be `\n` to replace it with `<br />`.

Comment: @Danijel was right, `\R` made it. I will use this solution  . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691) instead for this case. By default this matches Unicode newline sequences.

```
preg_match('/(.+)\R+/', $_POST['text'], $title);
echo $title[1];
```

**Reference**:

- [PHP Regex: How to match \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691)

Comment: thanks for your response, Danijel was the first who offer this and this is work for me, thanks for help.

Comment: @flinth no worries, I would check out the reference answer if you ever run into this problem again, it explains `\R`