# R removing unicode linebreaks

Tags: regex, r

I have Unicode newline characters in a string in which I need to remove.

These characters can be carriage return `\U000D`, newline `\U000A`, line separator or paragraph separator.

I am able to remove the carriage return and newline characters by using the following.

```
gsub("\\s", "", x)
```

Like I said this works fine for those Unicode characters, but I am not able to remove the the line separator `\U2028` or paragraph separator `\U2029` characters.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Include them in the regular expression: [\\s\u2028\u2029] for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch on [`PCRE`](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) using `perl=T` and utilize the handy escape sequence ([**`\R`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691))

```
> x <- 'foo\U000D\U000A bar\U2029 baz\U2028\U2029'
> x
## [1] "foo\r\n bar\u2029 baz\u2028\u2029"
> gsub('\\R', '', x, perl=T)
## [1] "foo bar baz"
```