# Split string in php with comma and new line

Tags: php, regex, string

Im trying to split string in PHP. I should split string using two delimiters: new line and comma. My code is:

```
$array = preg_split("/\n|,/", $str)
```

But i get string split using comma, but not using \n. Why is that? Also , do I have to take into account "\r\n" symbol?

Comment: This code worked fine for me when I tested it. Also, yes, I would suggest taking `\r\n` into account.

Answer (score 9):

I can think of two possible reasons that this is happening.

`1.` You are using a single quoted string:

```
    $array = preg_split("/\n|,/", 'foo,bar\nbaz');
    print_r($array);

    Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar\nbaz
    )
```

If so, use double quotes `"` instead ...

```
    $array = preg_split("/\n|,/", "foo,bar\nbaz");
    print_r($array);

    Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
        [2] => baz
    )
```

`2.` You have multiple newline sequences and I would recommend using [**`\R`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691) if so. This matches any Unicode newline sequence that is in the `ASCII` range.

```
    $array = preg_split('/\R|,/', "foo,bar\nbaz\r\nquz");
    print_r($array);

    Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
        [2] => baz
        [3] => quz
    )
```