# A multi-line, variedly greedy, regular expression

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-greedy

Given the following text, what PCRE regular expression would you use to extract the parts marked in bold?

```
00:20314 lorem ipsum
  want this
  kryptonite

00:02314 quux
  padding
  dont want this

00:03124 foo
     neither this

00:01324 foo
     but we want this
     stalagmite

00:02134 tralala
     not this

00:03124 bar foo
     and we want this
     kryptonite but not this(!)

00:02134 foo bar
     and not this either

00:01234 dolor sit amet
     EOF
```

IOW, we want to extract sections that start, in regex terms, with "^0" and end with  "(kryptonite|stalagmite)".

Been chomping on this for a bit, finding it a hard nut to crack. TIA!

Comment: A couple of ways to do it. Can the delimiters be in the body?

Comment: The only thing that delimits this requires no other `^0` in the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) combined with inline `(?sm)` [dotall and multi-line modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html).

```
(?sm)^0(?:(?!^0).)*?(?:kryptonite|stalagmite)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI6cZ6/3)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it works.

```
 # (?ms)^0(?:(?!(?:^0|kryptonite|stalagmite)).)*(kryptonite|stalagmite)

 (?ms)
 ^ 0
 (?:
      (?!
           (?: ^ 0 | kryptonite | stalagmite )
      )
      . 
 )*
 ( kryptonite | stalagmite )
```

Comment: Same concept, but you include the keywords as well. Nice =)

Comment: The keyword's probably not needed. Yours is the better one.

Comment: Still, think alike =) (+1)

Comment: Its the only way really.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will be the most efficient:

```
^0(?:\R(?!\R)|.)*?\b(?:kryptonite|stalagmite)\b
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/xZ0eL6/1)

---

Obviously we start with `^0` and then end with either `kryptonite` or `stalagmite` (in a non-capturing group, for the heck of it) surrounded by [`\b` word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

`(?:\R(?!\R)|.)*?` is the interesting part though, so let's break it down. One key concept first is PCRE's [`\R` newline sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691).

```
(?:      (?# start non-capturing group for repetition)
  \R     (?# match a newline character)
  (?!\R) (?# not followed by another newline)
 |       (?# OR)
  .      (?# match any character, except newline)
)*?      (?# lazily repeat this group)
```

Comment: You need to add `$` to your expression

Comment: @HamZa, I don't believe so: `00:03124 bar foo and we want this kryptonite but not this(!)`

Answer (score -1):

^(00:.*?(kryptonite|stalagmite))  with the s modifier

Comment: Simply doesn't match the expected output