# How do I remove linebreaks followed by a whitespace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to remove all line breaks followed by a whitespace or in other words; move all lines that starts with a whitespace to the end of the last line.

Example:

```
$str_before = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
 of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard dummy text ever since the";
```

Wanted result:

```
$str_after = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard dummy text ever since the";
```

I have tried this with no success:

```
$str_after = str_replace("\n"." "," ", $str_before)
```

How do I achieve this using php/regex?

Comment: I guess you will need to write some code.

Comment: If you are reading line by line, you can use trim() function.

Comment: @henninghall - all your lines starts from upper sign and end at dot?

Comment: @tanjir Might try it but would prefer to use a regex if posible

Comment: @henninghall so it's be hard to create regex :( or i'm too dump :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant but this should work.

```
<?php

$str = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
 of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s 
standard dummy text ever since the';

$newStr = []; $i = 0;
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $str) as $line) {
  $i++;

  if ($line[0] == chr(32)) {
    $newStr[$i-1] .= $line;
  } else {
    $newStr[$i] = $line;
  }
} 
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $newStr);
```

Comment: (Instead of the `\r` and `\n` combinations, one could often use `\R`, which [covers most linebreak variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n).)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex:

`^([^\n]*)\n( [^\n]*)$`
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rO9qB7/1).

Find everything in the file that matches. Replace with the first and second capturing group concatenated together.

Comment: Looks good but didn't work in my case of some reason.