# Exploding a string at 2 newlines as oppose to just 1

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I'm trying to explode a string that has more than 1 newline. More specifically, 2 newlines, and I'm not sure how to do it. For example:

```
$text = "
text1

text2

text3
";

$text = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
```

There would be some empty indexes in the array after this. I need to explode at 2 newlines instead of one. How do I do that?

Comment: You can also use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with pattern `/\R{2}/` to match `\r\n\r\n` or `\n\n`. `$res = preg_split('/\R{2}/', trim($text));` [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/422565); See [this answer what \R matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691/3110638).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure on how the newlines are formed (they may contain \n and/or \r), you can do it this way:

```
$Array = explode("\n\n", $text);
```

You can also trim the string, to remove newlines at the start and end:

```
$Array = explode("\n\n", trim($text));
```

Comment: "\n" will not always be appropriate - either in files generated with a Windows editor (with OS settings), or when coming from an HTML form field. I recommend using preg_split in this case and accepting "\r?\n" as the newline pattern to be more accommodating (the "\n\r" and "\r" forms have drifted into obsolescence).

Comment: @user2864740, I have added an alert about newline variations, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

Just use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the flag: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` set and explode the string with the constant `PHP_EOL`, e.g.

```
$arr = preg_split("/". PHP_EOL . "/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => text1 [1] => text2 [2] => text3 )
```