# Ul tag. How to identify the begin and end of a list with Regex

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I have a lot of different blog posts in a database. They are in markdown. I want to convert them to html. I have problems with the ul tag.

For instance in a simplified way I have that:

```
Something
- First
- Second
Something else

Second ul
- First
- Second
Some final text
```

I could put the li tags:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^- (.*)/m", "<li>$1</li>", $text);
```

But how can I identify the beginning or end of the list to put the ul tag?

I want this result:

```
Something
<ul>
<li>- First</li>
<li>- Second</li>
</ul>
Something else

Second ul
<ul>
<li>- First</li>
<li>- Second</li>
</ul>
Some final text
```

Comment: Using regex is perhaps not the ideal approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two passes, so with two `preg_replace` calls:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^- (.*)/m", "<li>$1</li>", 
            preg_replace("/^- .*(\R- .*)*/m", "<ul>\n$0\n</ul>", $text)
        );
```

The inner one executes first, and finds lines that starts with `-` and captures all the following lines that also start with `-` until the line that follows does not start `-`.

`.*` matches anything up to the end of the current line. The new line character is not matched by `.`. So the next [`\R`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) is used for matching anything considered a linebreak sequence. And then again the hyphen check is done and the remainder of the line is captured. This can repeat (`( ... )*`) as many times as possible.

That matched block is then wrapped in an `ul` tag. The hyphens are not removed at this stage.

The outer one will wrap lines that start with `-` in `li` tags, taking out the `-`.

Comment: Explain your inner one, please. What is \R?

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: I have been searching and I could not find any reference about \R is this like a generic that encompass \n and \r ?

Comment: There is a hyperlink on [`\R`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) in my answer ;-) See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n/18992691#18992691).