# Regex Splitting with optionally second line

Tags: regex

I want to split the text above in three results.
Every result starts with the word "Leistung" and can optionally have a second line starting with "Zusatz".

My regex-expression ist currently this:

```
/Leistung [ ]*[\w\d äöüÄÖÜ]*\n[\w\d äöüÄÖÜ\*]*/gm
```

But this does not fit exactly.

This ist the text:

```
Leistung             Armeotraining ET                                                         Anzahl 1
Zusatz               *TextZusatz_Anf1*
Leistung             Atemtherapie 30                                                          Anzahl 2
Leistung             Aktivierungsgruppe                                                       Anzahl 3
Zusatz               *TextZusatz_Anf3*
```

The result should be:

```
Leistung             Armeotraining ET                                                         Anzahl 1
Zusatz               *TextZusatz_Anf1*

Leistung             Atemtherapie 30                                                          Anzahl 2

Leistung             Aktivierungsgruppe                                                       Anzahl 3
Zusatz               *TextZusatz_Anf3*
```

Can anyone help me with the regex-expression?
Thank you in advance!

Tobias

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```bash
/Leistung.*(?:\n(?!Leistung).*)?/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Faz1Au/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `(?:\n(?!Leistung).*)?`: only capture the second line if it does not start with Leistung

Answer (score 1):

You can split at newlines if the word `Leistung` is [ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\n(?=Leistung\b)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mfSCKo/1) - `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Use `\r?\n` for *crlf* or [`\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691/5527985) if supported (eg PCRE/PHP).

Comment: Short and sweet

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work for me. I get no result with that!?

Comment: @TobiasGregorczyk What tool/lang are you using?

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me first:

```
/Leistung.*(?:\n(?!Leistung).*)?/gm
```

But then the situation chanced because there could be multile lines between the keyword "Leistung".
E.g.:

```
              Neurologische Diagnostik NTC aus MHK - Anforderung
Leistung             xDoppler-/Duplex-Sonographie der extracraniellen     Anzahl 1
                     hirnversorgenden Arterien
                     hier geht es weiter
Zusatz               Zusatz für Lst 1
Leistung             xDoppler-/Duplex-Sonographie der transcraniellen     Anzahl 1
                     hirnversorgenden Arterien
Zusatz               Zusatz für Lst 2

Auftragsdatum        17.10.2022 13:02
```

I didn't get a solution for that. Can anyone help?

Comment: How about changing your quantifiers: [`Leistung.*(?:\n(?!Leistung).+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/VD362h/1) (any amount, no empty lines)

Comment: In https://regex101.com/ `Leistung .*(?:\n(?!Leistung).+)*` it looks good!
But in TCL I got the line "Auftragsdatum" at the end.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Are you sure, you've used  `.+)*` at the end? Another idea to match at least one non-whitespace in each line, [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/q9eXpR/1): `Leistung.*(?:\n(?!Leistung)[ \t]*\S.*)*`

Comment: Great, the last one works! Thanks!