# Perl, use regex to find a match and replace just the last character of the match (in this case a line break)

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have to clean several csv files before i put them in a database, some of the files have a unexpected linebreak in the middle of the line, as the line should always end with a number i managed to fix the files with this one liner:

```
perl -pe 's/[^0-9]\r?\n//g'
```

while it did work it also replaces the last char before the line break

```
foob
ar
```

turns into

```
fooar
```

Is there any one liner perl that i can call that would follow the same rule without replacing the last char before the linebreak

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use [`\K` lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK)

```
perl -pe 's/[^0-9]\K\r?\n//g'
```

Now it drops all matches up to `\K` so only what follows it is subject to the replacement side.

---

However, I'd rather recommend to process your CSV with a library, even as it's a little more code. There's already been one problem, that linefeed inside a field, what else may be there? A good library can handle a variety of irregularities.

A simple example with [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file.csv\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 }); 

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
    s/\n+//g for @$row; 
    $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Consider other [constructor options](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm#accessors), also available via accessors, that are good for all kinds of unexpected problems.  Like `allow_whitespace` for example.

This can be done as a command-line program ("one-liner") as well, if there is a reason for that. The library's functional interface via [csv](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm#csv) is then convenient

```
perl -MText::CSV=csv -we' 
   csv in => *ARGV, on_in => sub { s/\n+//g for @{$_[1]} }' filename
```

With `*ARGV` the input is taken either from a file named on command line or from `STDIN`.

Answer (score 4):

A *negative* [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which is an assertion and won't consume characters can also be used.

```
(?<!\d)\R
```

- `\d` is a a [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *digit*
- `\R` [matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691/5527985) any *linebreak sequence*

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0z2Eop/1)

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice regex. So I assume `\R` is matching literal new lines? I asked other day 1 more expert but I couldn't understand it honestly, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 There is a [nice answer from @hwnd according `\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691/5527985). It matches any linebreak sequence (added this better link to my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Just capture the last char and put it back:

```
perl -pe 's/([^0-9])\r?\n/$1/g'
```