# PHP regex indicating Arabic string contains carriage return when str_contains returns false

Tags: php, regex, unicode, php-8

```
<?php
$foo='تذوق لحظات الطعام والشراب اللذيذة';
var_dump(preg_match('/\R/', $foo));
var_dump(str_contains($foo, "\r"));
?>
```

the output of the above is that the `preg_match` returns `1` indicating a match but the `str_contains` returns `false` (as I'd expect since I see no carriage return?).

Is this some issue relating to performing regex searches on non-ASCII strings?

You can demo this [here](https://onlinephp.io/c/1ccce)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Regex: How to match \r and \n without using \[\r\n\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988536/php-regex-how-to-match-r-and-n-without-using-r-n). See the `u` modifier in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691/2257664). Here is the result: https://onlinephp.io/c/3031e

Comment: Your string contains the byte `\x85` that is the NEL (Next Line) character in ASCII. `\R` matches this character too. If you switch to utf-8 mode with the u modifier, `\R` will match `\xc2\x85` for the NEL character. Whatever, your string doesn't contain a carriage return.